# How to get rid of every possible website data on phone

Tags: android, css, google-chrome, caching, browser-cache

I have an issue with displaying an image in my web app and I can't think of any other reason but some strange cache situation. The image has the following CSS properties so its always showing a square part of the image:

```css
object-fit: cover;
height: 100vw;
width: 100%;
```

Now when I test the app on my phone the image gets stretched like object-fit isn't supported by the browser. But when I test the same on my girlfriend's phone it works perfectly. Strange part is that we have the exact same phone(samsung s10e) running the same os and using the same browser(Chrome for Android) and browser version (83+). I tried reinstalling and deleting temp data from any browser installed but I can't get it to work. The app is using a web app manifest but no service worker (yet) if this helps.

If someone has any clue how to go from here please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You should clear your browser cache. Here's how...

Open chrome and click more. Click more tools then clear browsing data. Choose a time rage or all time. Check cookies and other site data and cached images and files. You can try just clearing cached images and files first but for a full clear do the other one (this one may sign you out of most sites)
Clear clear data and your done.

If it's that you want your one web page not to be cached on all browsers (supported ones only) then look into the pragma meta tag.

Comment: "deleting temp data from any browser installed" this part refered to me deleting every cache possible. But thanks for your tip anyways :)